# MondogDB Create index for nested array

Tags: mongodb, indexing

I have this object

```
{
"sales": [
   [
     {
       "id": "123"
     }
   ]
]
}
```

May i add an index on the "id" field? How?

Comment: Is there something wrong with the simple `db.collection.createIndex( {"sales.id": 1 } )`?

Comment: It doesn't work since id is nested in 2 arrays

Comment: What "doesn't work"? The index cannot be created? Or the index is created but your query cannot use the created index?

Comment: And if the latter, what does your query look like?

Comment: Yes, in the query the index is not used, this is the query
db.getCollection("sales").find({ 
    sales: { 
        $elemMatch: { 
            $elemMatch: { "id" : "0846474541" }
        } 
    } 
})
.explain("executionStats")

Comment: @Premier [edit] your question to include details instead of putting them in comments.

Comment: Is there any reason why you cannot do a simple `db.sales.find({
  "sales.id": "0846474541"
}).explain("executionStats")` like [this](https://mongoplayground.net/p/8LQMxO3zZ2-)?

Answer (score 0):

> { "sales": [ [ { "id": "123" } ] ] }

Firstly, This case is about "indexing nested arrays". One minor observation is that the outer array does not have a key. Is it intentional ? If intentional, is there any chance of reviewing the schema. The following 2 points would provide more about it.

> { "sales": [ x: [ { "id": "123" } ] ] }

Secondly, the above schema means x is a nested array of the array "sales". Is this the kind of schema you are looking for ?. If so, a compound index "sales.x.id" would normally be supported.

Thirdly, you may be able to see a similar case handled in the following link.
[MongoDB query optimisation for nested array of objects](https://www.mongodb.com/community/forums/t/mongodb-query-optimisation-for-nested-array-of-objects/16786)

Thank you
WeDoTheBest4You